# How does numpy.array choose default data type?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

The `numpy.array()` function seems to behave rather strangely when some numbers in the order of `2**64` are involved and no data type is specified.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is it a bug or is it expected?

```
$ python3
Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov 30 2022, 10:05:23) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.23.5'
>>> np.array([2**63-1]).dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> np.array([2**64-1]).dtype
dtype('uint64')
```

So far, I think it makes sense, `int64` is probably the default, but it can't represent `2**64-1` so it switches to `uint64`.

```
>>> np.array([2**64-1, 2**63-1]).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Now that I've added some other number, which perfectly fits in `uint64` as well, it suddently changes to `float64`.

```
>>> np.array([2**65-1]).dtype
dtype('O')
```

OK, `2**65-1` requires some kind of larger integer representation.

```
>>> np.array([2**64-1, 2**65-1]).dtype
dtype('O')
```

This isn't just weird, but it also affects precision:

```
>>> int(np.round(np.array([2**64-1])[0]))
18446744073709551615
>>> int(np.round(np.array([2**64-1, 2**63-1])[0]))
18446744073709551616
>>> int(np.round(np.array([2**64-1, 2**65-1])[0]))
18446744073709551615
```

In these 3 expressions, the 1st and 3rd are evaluated without loss of precision, but the 2nd one gets rounded due to the conversion to float and back to int.  Why is the 2nd expression using floats while a perfectly accurate integer type is clearly available?

Comment: Huh... looks like it might be deciding dtypes on a per-element basis, then picking an array dtype based on those per-element dtypes without considering their values. So `2**64-1` is considered a uint64, `2**63-1` is considered an int64, and then NumPy decides there's no integer dtype big enough to hold all uint64 and int64 values, so it does that awkward thing it sometimes does with mixed uint64/int64 operations and converts everything to float64.

Comment: @user2357112 That actually makes sense in some weird way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, [NumPy issue 19146](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19146). (I'm not sure it crosses the line to be called a bug, but it's definitely an issue.) It looks like there might have been some effort to change the behavior a few years ago, but it doesn't look like anything ended up happening.

NumPy's uint64 treatment has a lot of awkward cases like this. There's no integer dtype big enough to hold all values of uint64 dtype and any signed dtype, so code that'd promote to a bigger integer dtype when operating on smaller dtypes instead promotes to float64. Similar awkwardness happens when trying to do basic arithmetic:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.uint64(1) + 1  # float64 result!
Out[2]: 2.0

In [3]: numpy.uint64(1) << 1  # error!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 numpy.uint64(1) << 1

TypeError: ufunc 'left_shift' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Any idea why they are not considering `object` as a valid integer type they can promote to?

Comment: @PieterNuyts: Maybe the severe performance penalty, maybe some sort of historical reason.